# What does the idiom ‘I don’t want to be the Babylonian messenger‘ mean?

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

Is it related to the idiom ‘don’t shoot the messenger’?

Comment: Neither I nor Google recognise "Babylonian messenger" as an idiom. There are a couple of Old Testament references to messengers to and from Babylon returned but nothing specific. I suppose that it might refer to "the writing on the wall" from the story of [Beshazzar's Feast](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belshazzar%27s_feast) in the Book of Daniel. "The writing on the wall" _is_ an idiom (meaning a warning of disaster). The writing _was_ a message and Beshazzar _was_ a Babylonian king but the message was written by a disembodied hand from God. Can you give more context please?

Comment: Is this in reference to the following line from Paddy Chayefsky's screenplay for [_The Network_](https://books.google.com/books?id=b94WAQAAMAAJ&q=%22Babylonian+messenger%22&dq=%22Babylonian+messenger%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjp-7rNodLuAhWHHDQIHZQCBvQ4ChDoATAJegQIAhAC): "DONNELLY: Well, I don't want to be the **Babylonian messenger** who has to tell Max Schumacher about this"?

Comment: Judah, or the "Southern Kingdom" in a divided Israel, experienced the "Babylonian Captivity" in the 6th century BC. Thousands (perhaps tens of thousands) of citizens of Judah were dragged off to Babylon as a punishment by God for various national sins. A Babylonian messenger, then, could be a bearer of bad news. the messenger would say to Judah's king, Jehoiachin: "Your country is about to be defeated and taken over by Babylon's superior army. Resistance will be futile! Your subjects will be taken into exile and your capital city of Jerusalem will be sacked."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it's a reference to Jeremiah 51:31 in which a relay of messengers run to tell the king of Babylon that his city has been taken.

As far as the king is concerned these are not glad tidings. So your expression might be be equivalent to "I hate to be the bearer of bad news".

But if you're devout you're meant to be glad to hear Babylon has fallen, in which case your expression would mean, "I don't want to be the bearer of **good** news": a position most people would *envy*.

Comment: Presumably if you're a Babylonian messenger, what you're worried about is the king killing you when he hears the news, not whether the fall of Babylon is a good thing in world historical terms.

Comment: Aha! Yes. It's probably that. In a relay the fastest runner does usually go last though. Let's hope he got away.